# Can Recursion be avoided here? find minimum ways in which one string can be transformed into another

Tags: java, recursion

Can Recursion be avoided here? Java code here deals with two strings. find minimum ways in which one string can be transformed into another. at a time we can delete char, add char or replace char from Strings.

public class MinimumWays {

```
public static int colorSequences(String input1,String input2)
{


    return new MinimumWays().transform(input1, input2);
}

public int transform(String inp1, String inp2){
    int a  = 0; int b=0; int c=0; int result =0;
    if(inp1.length()==0){
        result = inp2.length();
        return result;
    }
    else if(inp2.length()==0){
        result =inp1.length();
        return result;
    }
    if(inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1).equals(inp2)||inp1.substring(1, inp1.length()).equals(inp2)){
         a=0;
         return a;
    }
    else{
        a = Math.min(transform(inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1), inp2), transform(inp1.substring(1, inp1.length()), inp2) );
    }
    if(inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1).equals(inp1)||inp2.substring(1,inp2.length()).equals(inp1)){
         b=0;
         return b;
    }
    else{
        b = Math.min(transform(inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1), inp1),transform(inp2.substring(1,inp2.length()), inp1));
    }
    if(inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1).equals(inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1))|| 
            inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1).equals(inp1.substring(1, inp1.length())) || 
              inp2.substring(1, inp2.length()).equals(inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1)) ||
                inp2.substring(1, inp2.length()).equals(inp1.substring(1, inp1.length()))){
         c=0;
         return c;
    }
    else{
        int c1 = transform(inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1), inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1));
        int c2 = transform(inp2.substring(1, inp2.length()), inp1.substring(0, inp1.length()-1));
        int c3 = transform(inp2.substring(0, inp2.length()-1), inp1.substring(1, inp1.length()));
        int c4 = transform(inp2.substring(1, inp2.length()), inp1.substring(1, inp1.length()));
        c = Math.min(Math.min(c1, c2), Math.min(c3, c4));
    }

    result = 1+Math.min(a, Math.min(c, b));
    return result;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "sakdh";
    String input2 = "akh";
    System.out.println("Minimum Ways: " + colorSequences(input1, input2));

}
```

}

Although functionally herenworks fine, but for large Strings(even for 6-7 char) it is taking lot of time. I am not able to figure out any other way to code it. :-(

Comment: Could you explain, what is your program intended to do? Some input-output samples would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean, but you can iterate over (or just count) all permutations of the string's characters without recursion, as per Knuth's Algorithm L. [Here](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/04/lexicographic-permutations-using.html) is an implementation in Python.

Comment: @Christian: e.g. String 1: "asghm", String 2: "kasgfh". Now to convert str1 into str 2, operations are 1. add k at 0, 2. add f between g&h, 3. add m at last. So minimum ways here is 3.

Comment: Concept applied in above code is:
min ways of A[1,2..m]B[1,2,..n] = 1 + min{min ways of A[1,2..m-1]B[1,2,..n] , min ways of A[1,2..m]B[1,2,..n-1], min ways of A[1,2..m-1]B[1,2,..n-1]}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the "edit distance" problem. There is a more efficient way of solving this problem . Withdynamic programming this problem is O(MN), with M and N being the number of characters in each string. Here is some material on the subject...

http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Lec6-EditDistance.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is edit distance, a common two-dimensional dynamic programming problem. You can solve using recursion and memoization or iteratively.

Try this:

```
HashMap<List<String>, Integer> memo = new HashMap<List<String>, Integer>();

public int transform(String inp1, String inp2){
{
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp.add(inp1);
    temp.add(inp2);
    if (memo.containsKey(temp))
    {
        return memo.get(temp);
    }
    ...
```

Other people are going to beat me to it but then make sure you store the answer into the HashMap prior to returning. This will make calls to the function return instantly if they have already been calculated, rather than recalculating.

Comment: Wikipedia link for those interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: I have tried this. Although there is very slight improvement in efficiency, it frequently fails with OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Woops. Looks like Java's arrays can't be used as a key because the object is hashed rather than its contents. Lists should work fine.